# What is a blocking function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, real-time, terminology, blocking

What is a *blocking function* or a *blocking call*?

This is a term I see again and again when referring to Node.js or realtime processing languages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A function that stops script execution until it ends.

For example, if I had a function in my language that was used to write to a file, like so:

```
fwrite(file, "Contents");
print("Wrote to file!");
```

The `print` statement would only be executed once the file has been written to the disk. The whole program is **halted** on this instruction. This isn't noticeable for small enough writes, but imagine I had a huge blob to write to the file, one that took many seconds:

```
fwrite(file, blob);
print("Wrote to file!");
```

The `print` statement would only be executed after a few seconds of writting, and the whole program would be stopped for that time. In Node.js, this stuff is done **asynchronously**, using **events** and **callbacks**. Our example would become:

```
fwrite(file, blob, function() {
    print("Wrote to file!");
});
print("Do other stuff");
```

Where the third parameter is a function to be called once the file has been written. The `print` statement located after the write function would be called immediately after, whether or not the file has been written yet. So if we were to write a huge enough blob, the output might look like this:

```
Do other stuff
Wrote to file!
```

This makes applictions very **fast** because you're not waiting on a client message, a file write or other. You can keep on processing the data in a parallel manner. This is considered by many one of the strengths of Node.js.

Answer (score 3):

```
var block = function _block() {
  while(true) {
    readInputs();
    compute();
    drawToScreen();
  }
}
```

A blocking function basically computes forever. That's what it means by blocking.

Other blocking functions would wait for IO to occur

a non-blocking IO system means a function starts an IO action, then goes idle then handles the result of the IO action when it happens.

It's basically the difference between a thread idling and sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

A blocking call is one that doesn't allow processing to continue until it returns to the calling thread - this is also referred to as a synchronous call. Asynchronous on the other hand means that threads (and code) can execute at the same time (concurrently).