# How to get back values from my sql database in int for discord.py

Tags: sql, discord.py, wampserver

I tired creating a database for a economy kind of game in discord.py, I suceeded in making a create profile command but ran across a error in the following code, the problem being that the value mycursor.fetch gives back is not defined as string as such i can't add it to a, i also intend to make a command to show the amount of wood so i need help to get the value as int and such

````
async def chop(ctx):
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    mycursor.execute(f"Select Wood from Record where UID='{ctx.author.id}'")
    x=mycursor.fetchall()
    print(x)
    a=random.randrange(0,300)
    p=a+x
    c=f"UPDATE Record SET Wood ={p} WHERE UID ='{ctx.author.id}';"
    l=discord.Embed(description=f"You have chopped down {a} Wood", color=0x800000)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=l)```
````

Comment: You are defining the cursor as `cursor`, but using `mycursor` for the rest of the commands, is this a copy paste issue, or is that the real code

Comment: Yeah it's a copypaste issue the code ran i am sure it's fine the problem is that when i retrieve x it's in string and i can't add it to a

Comment: what sql and what connector are you using?

Comment: ```import mysql.connector 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="Economy")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='Economy',)

```

Answer (score -1):

Sql commands:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> (<row1> INTEGER, <row2> TEXT) #creates a table

SELECT * FROM <table_name> #to get all rows fron table
SELECT <row1>, <row2> FROM <table_name> #To get 2 rows from table
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <row1>=<value> #to get rows where row1 is our spesific value

DELETE FROM <table_name> #delete all rows
DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE <row1>=<value> #deletes a spesific row

UPDATE <table_name> SET <row1>=<new_value>, <row2>=<new_value2> WHERE <row1>=<current_value> #updates rows
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok first of all, you shouldn't be using mysql-connector for a discord.py bot, it is [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407165/what-is-a-blocking-function). Try using something like [aiomysql](https://pypi.org/project/aiomysql/)

In regards to your code,
`mycursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples containing the values fetched. Play around with this a bit before actually using it in a bot.

```py
x = mycursor.fetchall()

wood = x[0][0] #this is the actual value
wood += a
#update database here
```

References:-

- [`cursor.fetchall`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)